# CSS keyframes different speed in different browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I createad a effect with keyframes that zooms into a picture and moves it as well (Ken Burns effect).

Everything works fine until I use different browsers. On Chrome its rather slow and the exact speed that I want it to but on Firefox the animation is way faster. I've set the timespan to 30s.

```
    .image-kenburns {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: kenburns 30s linear infinite;
    height: 270px;
    width: 100%;
}

@keyframes kenburns {


    0% {
         transform: scale(1.0);
         -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
         -o-transform: scale(1.0);
         -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
        background-position: top center;
     }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
        -moz-transform-origin: bottom right;
        -ms-transform-origin: bottom right;
        -o-transform-origin: bottom right;
        transform-origin: bottom right;
        transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        background-position: bottom center;
    }

    75% {
        -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
        -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
        -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
        -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
        transform-origin: bottom center;
        transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        background-position: bottom center;
    }



    100% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        -o-transform: scale(1.0);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
        background-position: top center;
    }
}
```

Is there any way for me to set the speed for the different browsers?

Edit:

As mentioned in the comments I should be able to use only 1 vendor prefix? I need support for all browsers.
Also mentioned : `animation-duration` doesn't seem to work for me. I tried it with Firefox by setting the duration way higher but it didn't affect it at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to set `-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;` (set what seconds you want)

Comment: you no more need all the vendor prefixes, you can start by removing them

Comment: Didnt work for me with webkit animation.. What vendor prefix do I need to use then?